# How can I make an authorized fetch request to a Google API?

Tags: swift, xcode, oauth-2.0

I am trying to be able to make a fetch request and get back data  in SwiftUI.

The google Sign in setup in the app delegate in my app looks like this:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, GIDSignInDelegate {


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    
    FirebaseApp.configure()
    // Intializing Google Sign In...
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().scopes = []
        
        
        
//        FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID = "674329356626-ev6hn62oiqcj0o228nt85vv2bgroa45j.apps.googleusercontent.com"
        return true
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any])
  -> Bool {
  return GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().handle(url)
}

func sign(_ signIn: GIDSignIn!, didSignInFor user: GIDGoogleUser!, withError error: Error!) {

    if error != nil{

        print(error.localizedDescription)
        return
    }

    let credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credential(withIDToken: user.authentication.idToken, accessToken: user.authentication.accessToken)

    // Logging to Firebase...
    Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (res, err) in

        if err != nil{

            print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
            return
        }
        // User Logged In Successfully...
        // Sending Notification To UI...
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("SIGNIN"), object: nil)
        // Printing Email ID
        print(res?.user.email)
    }

    // Check for sign in error
            if let error = error {
                if (error as NSError).code == GIDSignInErrorCode.hasNoAuthInKeychain.rawValue {
                    print("The user has not signed in before or they have since signed out.")
                } else {
                    print("\(error.localizedDescription)")
                }
                return
            }

            // Post notification after user successfully sign in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .signInGoogleCompleted, object: nil)
}



// MARK: UISceneSession Lifecycle

func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
    // Called when a new scene session is being created.
    // Use this method to select a configuration to create the new scene with.
    return UISceneConfiguration(name: "Default Configuration", sessionRole: connectingSceneSession.role)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
    // Called when the user discards a scene session.
    // If any sessions were discarded while the application was not running, this will be called shortly after application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.
    // Use this method to release any resources that were specific to the discarded scenes, as they will not return.
}

}
```

Currently I can click on a button which will bring a prompt asking me to sign into google and asking if I would like to allow access to certain permission that I have listed in the 'scopes' property above in the code.

After signed in I make a fetch request which should send back a list of data.  However, I get back a 401 error which means an unauthorized request.

**How can I make a fetch request which authorized?**

Thank you for any help in advance.